# A problem of volume calculation with AutoLisp

Tags: autolisp

Hello to all and here's the problem.

I am thinking about creating the following program in AutoCAD's AutoLisp language: say we need to calculate the volume of a surface of rectangular basis, enclosed from above with a sorface determined by given terrain level curves (such level curves represent points of equal height, and hence give an interpolatory idea of how the terrain surface looks like).

My first idea is interpolation up to an arbitrary degree of accuracy, i.e. meshing the base area and then calculating the height at the center of every (say) rectangular mesh element. Hence, the volume equals the product of the rectangles sides with the sum of all such heights.

Now, the problem is to determine these heights. The above mentioned terrain level curves are usually given as polylines. So, for every point where the height is to be sought, one needs to determine between which two such polylines the point lies, in order to interpolate the height of the point based on values which are represented by neighbouring polylines.

I'm not really sure how to attack this problem, so any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you could start by making tins from the 2 surfaces. See explanation and code [here](http://paulbourke.net/papers/triangulate/)
Then you could determine a grid over these surfaces and get the height in the center. The difference between both heights and the gridsize will help you to determine the volume.

This is no easy task.

Have you looked at AutoDesk Civil 3D? That has some good volume calculating tools.